# How do I pass variables in mongojs query in the key name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

Each document in my users collection looks like this:
`access: { 123456789012345678901234: 3, 123456789012345678901235: 2, 123456789012345678901234: 1, 123456789012345678901236: 0 }`

I'm trying to find all records which have `access.123456789012345678901234` greater than 0 and this is how I wrote the function. (The value 123456789012345678901234 is passed to the function in the parameter companyid)

```
findUsersInCompany: function(companyid, callback) {
    base.db.users.find({ "access." + companyid: { "$gt": 0 } }, function(err, usersList) {
        if( err ) callback(err);
        else if( _.isEmpty(usersList) ) callback(1016);
        else callback( null, usersList );
    });
}
```

However, I get an error which says 'Unexpected token +'

Any help on how to get this to work would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build up your `find` selector ahead of the call like this:

```
var selector = {};
selector["access." + companyid] = { "$gt": 0 };        
base.db.users.find(selector, function(err, usersList) {
    ...
});
```